# XCode 4 project falls apart in XCode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a 6 month old app on the AppStore, which compiles and runs without problems using XCode 4.0.2 on Mac OS 10.6.8, and has no issues on any devices when purchased.

Recently, I wanted to roll out a new version and made some improvements that do not even involve a change in code. All looked good in the simulator, but when I tried to install my Ad-Hoc build, I ran into a problem: my devices are now running iOS 5.1.1 and it wouldn't install.

Restoring back to iOS 4 proved impossible, so I installed XCode 4.2 with iOS 5 SDK. (I'd be ok with upgrading to Lion as well but...)

The App completely fell apart when I tried to run it in the simulator, with about 50 issues here and there, and wouldn't even get past the first screen.

Although I can find my way around in the written code, I'm not a programmer, and have no clue as to how I could fix all those issues. Apart from hiring a programmer with each new iOS release, is my only option to directly release it on the AppStore and do my testing with a live product? (E.g. under a disposable App ID)

I just can't wrap my mind around as to why a product that runs perfectly fine on the actual device can not be run on the test bed.

Thanks for putting up with my rookie question, I really would appreciate your guidance.

(Screenshot of warnings: http://www.sunnyphotography.com/_temp/warnings.png )

Comment: You might need to check if ARC was accidentally turned on.  Xcode just doesn't "break" for no reason.

Comment: @CodaFi, if ARC got *accidentally* turned on, his old, non-ARC code wouldn't even build.  It would complain about `retain`, `release`, etc. not being allowed.  He's describing installation and runtime errors.  To Serdar, unfortunately, Apple breaks things all the time.  They expect their developers (us) to constantly be upgrading to the latest toolsets, so this doesn't strike me as even slightly surprising.  Yes, I do think periodic maintenance from a developer is a realistic expectation (I say that without conflict of interest ... you obviously aren't going to hire me :) )

Comment: @Nate, that's the point.  ARC warnings, to a non-developer, are the same red flags he'd be getting if there were coding errors.  And besides, Xcode is set to build through errors (or until LLVM passes out from exhaustion), so the point is moot.  Finally:  ***HOW IN THE WORLD ARE THEY RUNTIME ERRORS IF IT DOESN'T EVEN BUILD!!!***

Comment: Installing, uninstalling, building and cleaning, my brain's gotten quite mushy, so I don't have the energy to re-install and try on 4.2 now at 3 am, but I do have a feeling that CodaFi may have hit the nail on the head. (And really really hope so!)

Comment: Here's what might help.  Click the name of the project at the top of the file tree on the left hand side, then click on the "Build Phases" Tab at the top right.  Expand the arrow next to "Build Sources", then highlight all of those files (cmd+A).  Hit the enter key, and in the resulting dialog, type "-fno-objc-arc” (sans quotes) and hit OK.

Comment: I wasn't done writing man, who do you have to screw around here to get a line break, lol!?. Anyway, as I didn't even know what on earth ARC was, I googled it and saw this: ( http://matthiaswessendorf.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/disabling-the-arc-in-xcode-4-2/ ) So that's what I'll try and report back on tomorrow. Thanks a million, you have no idea how much you've helped already as I now may be able to get some sleep!

Comment: @Sunny Any [more] details you can give us on the errors you are seeing would be useful and may help someone identify the issue you are seeing. CodaFi has made an excellent suggestion, but there may be other things going on. The more information you can provide, the better.

Comment: @CodaFi,  I can read your angry rants just fine without the bolded caps lock, thank you very much.  I didn't say it didn't build, and neither did the question (at least explicitly).  The question said, "and wouldn't even get past the first screen.".  That sounds like a runtime error.  If it doesn't build, then it doesn't even get *to* the first screen, much less past it.  One of the easiest ways for an old app to stop installing, or crash on the "splash" screen (Default.png) is code signing errors.  Profiles can expire over time, without anything actually changing in the code, or the toolset.

Comment: Alright, right back to frustration: I tried CodaFi's suggestion and added -fno-objc-arc as compiler flags, but that didn't change the number of warnings. Then I figured out how to check the ARC status, and verified that it's OFF, so that's not it then. Big bummer.

Comment: I now have 4.0.2 and 4.2 both installed. Builds and runs fine in 4.0.2 with base SDK 4.3. In 4.2 with base SDK 5, builds with 28 issues and loads up on simulator, but I can't get past the cover. (This is a book btw.) The debugging shows no errors, and does show the events as I swipe etc, as if all is working fine. So it's not crashing, it's more like the cover doesn't move out of the way to let me see the pages as I slide them. In any case, the (yellow) warnings include all kinds of stuff: Semantic issues and Unused Entity Issues.. Many of them about Expression result being unused.

Comment: Other than downloading the older firmware from iphonefirmware.com and trying restore via the option-click in iTunes (which has failed), there is no way to get iOS 4 on my devices, correct?

Comment: @Sunny: Can we see a screenshot of some of the warnings?

Comment: Screenshot: http://www.sunnyphotography.com/_temp/warnings.png